# take html input from user and out modified html back to the user

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box on my site that will take in HTML from the user. I want to be able to take that HTML and modify it and then output the new HTML back to the user. The changes would always be easy because I would only be replacing certain characters within that HTML. They would be the same characters each time.

I think the best way to do this would be to take each line and add it to an array. That way i can output each part of the array into a new line using a for loop or something. This would also preserve line breaks. But that still doesn't solve the HTML issue. Right now when I take in HTML and try to output it, i can't. It won't show up unless it's plain text.

Currently I can only do a single line of text by just using innerHTML.

Is there a way to do this with vanilla JS?

any suggestions on where i could look would be awesome! thank you.

Comment: I am sure there is. Can you show what you did so that we can better assist you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a prompt like so:

```
<html>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function getValue(){
           var retVal = prompt("Enter your name : ", "your name here");

  // You can do something like convert it all to lowercase here:
           document.write("You have entered : " + retVal.toLowerCase());
        }
  </script>
```

Click the following button to see the result:

```
  <form>
     <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="getValue();" />
  </form>
```

Thus returning modified user input to the user without posting anything or submitting a form. This is just a simple example, but you can take this and apply it to an input field with a button by adding

```
onclick="functionToDoSomething()"
```

as an attribute to the button, and having the function get and alter the value of the input field.